# List commits between 2 commit hashes in git

Tags: git, commit

I know there has been very similar questions here, but they didn't solve my problem.
Perhaps there's something I'm not understanding well.

This is a portion of the commit history of fitnesse (https://github.com/unclebob/fitnesse/):

```
* | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | fa86be8 Avoid possible issue when using CachingPage under heavy memory load.
|/ / / / / / / / / / / / / / /  
* | | | | | | | | | | | | | |   7b4a07a Merge pull request #256 from barredijkstra/fitnesse_issue_250
|\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  
| * | | | | | | | | | | | | | | ecf5891 Fixed test checking for OS specific exception message.
| * | | | | | | | | | | | | | | 082236e Added rendering of cause exceptions. Fix for unclebob/fitnesse#250
* | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |   a92b37f Merge pull request #243 from amolenaar/fix/243-hash-table-rendering
```

I want the list of commits between 2 commit hashes. In this particular case, I want the commits between `ecf5891` and `7b4a07a`, and I expect the result to be:

```
ecf5891
7b4a07a
```

Si far I've been using `git rev-list commit_hash_from_here^..commit_hash_up_to_here` and it has worked fine with linear history. However, in this case I get a lot more commits.

I've tried this and it works just as expected:

```
git log --since='<date ecf5891>' --until='<date 7b4a07a>'
```

(I've manually searched for those 2 dates).

One possible solution is to get the 2 dates and just do that, but I think there should be a better way.

Edit:
`7b4a07a` parents are `ecf5891` and `a92b37f`. So far, the solutions work fine if I want to go from `ecf5891` to `7b4a07a`, but if I want to go from `a92b37f` to `7b4a07a` I want to get:

```
7b4a07a
ecf5891
082236e
a92b37f
```

but I don't get `a92b37f`

Answer (score 102):

I think that you`re looking for [--ancestry-path](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list/#Documentation/git-rev-list.txt---ancestry-path), in your case:

```
git rev-list --ancestry-path 7b4a07a..ecf5891
```

Comment: `--ancestry-path` was the ticket for me.  I used it, in the end, in this way:

`git log --oneline --ancestry-path commit1~1..commit2`

in order to see everything exactly between my two commit hashes I had.  Thanks!

Comment: commit 1 needs to be the old commit and commit 2 the new one to make these commands work

Answer (score 43):

"Between" is a somewhat slippery notion, when it comes to git commits.

The text you show above, with a snippet of graph output, shows why *`from^..to`* produces more than just those two commits: the *`to`* part is a merge commit.

The notation *`A..B`* is really just shorthand for *`B ^A`*.  That is, "everything starting from *`B`* and working backwards, minus everything starting from *`A`* and working backwards".  But *`B`* is a merge commit, so "everything starting there and working backwards" uses *both parents*.

Here the first parent of `7b4a07a` is `a92b37f` (not in your [original] snippet above but I cloned the linked repo and found it).  We can refer to it symbolically, though, and I will below.  The second parent of `7b4a07a` is `ecf5891`, the "from" part you're interested in.

When you ask for:

```
ecf5891^..7b4a07a
```

that means:

```
7b4a07a ^ecf5891^
```

which is the same as:

```
7b4a07a ^082236e
```

which gets you both parents of the merge, and then trims off everything from `082236e` back.  You need to trim off everything from `7b4a07a^`—the first parent—and back as well:

```
git rev-list 7b4a07a ^ecf5891^ ^7b4a07a^
git log --oneline 7b4a07a ^ecf5891^ ^7b4a07a^
```

In general, though, you have to figure out which descendent line(s) to chop-off.

Edit: you can stick with the *`A..B`* notation, but you do need to add the extra "exclude".  So [jthill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18680059/1256452) works too, once you move the hat to the front.

---

Re your edit ("if I want to go from `a92b37f` to `7b4a07a`"): we're back to that issue of "between" being a slippery notion.  Which commits are "between"?  There's a direct line from `a92b37f` to `7b4a07a`, because `a92b37f` is one of the two parents of the merge commit `7b4a07a`.  So by the earlier logic ("commits directly on an ancestral line", perhaps "inclusive") that would just be one, or maybe both, of those two commits.  But you say you want two commits that are not, in any ancestral sense, related to `a92b37f` at all.  *Why* do you want those two particular commits?  What makes `082236e` "interesting" and `082236e^`, its parent, "uninteresting"?

Comment: Ok, I understand when you said "all the way back, but that applies to the 2 parents". Then, you do what I did before and chop-off the extra-parent part, by doing `^7b4a07a^` which is `^a92b37f`. How do you know that `7b4a07a^` is going to be "the other" parent and not `ecf5891`? I'm doing this in a script, so I can't manually look up.

Comment: "Aye, there's the rub" –Hamlet.  There's no way *a priori* to know which parent(s) of a merge to cut off, just from the commits themselves.  You'll have to provide (perhaps a lot) more background.

Comment: Right now I want the commits in chronological order, the notion of "between" would be: look for commit A and B in the chronological graph, all the commits between them including A and B. Perhaps it doesn't make much sense and I'm thinking too svn-way. So far, the solution has been the most easiest and ugly: get all commit hashes, search for A and add to list until I find B. Thank you anyway, you have cleared out some things and made me think if the chronological way is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Or, maybe it does make sense, and what you want *is* limiting with `--since` and `--until` (or `--min-age` and `--max-age` which do the same thing).  (Note, these look at "committer" dates rather than "author" dates, i.e., when the patch was committed, vs when it was written.)  But, yes, that's the question, what exactly does "between" mean when history is non-linear?

Comment: Thanks @torek. You saved my day! I have been banging my head to include the starting commit & "^" helped a lot.

Answer (score 28):

First identify the relevant 2 commit hashes that you need for getting the list of commit hashes in between them by using

```
git log --oneline
```

Then you can pick the relevant two commit hashes and find the commit hashes in between them by using

```
git log <commit hash 1>..<commit hash 2> --oneline | cut -d " " -f 1
```

Comment: Did you test this answer? Its [not producing expected results](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41688733) for me.

Comment: I needed to do the following: `git log --oneline hashone..hashtwo`

Comment: Funny, the "from" commit has to be older than the "to" commit, otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: why is the --online option necessary?! What is the difference between with --online and without?

Comment: @user12411795 `--oneline` is just a formatting flag. It prints the result on one line per commit, omitting some information.

Answer (score 3):

Add ^7b4a07a~ to also exclude everything reachable from the merge's first parent. You're only excluding what's reachable from its second parent.

Comment: Typo of sorts, you need the `^` in front (or `--not`)

Comment: Where should I add that part? How would be the complete line?

Comment: add it to the rest of your specification, just another argument.  @torek: :-P yow. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, that works so far. However, it doesn't work in the case I've provided in the edit.

Comment: You have all the tools you need to do it.  `git help revisions` will walk you through all the ways you can specify which revisions you want or don't.  The thing to understand is what it says in the description: commands that work on commit sets use "reachable from" and "not reachable from" specifications.  Now all you need is time and a bit of experimentation and play.

Comment: not showing the complete command. Not explaining what all the magic characters are doing.

Potentially one should add if this only applies to databases for which 

git pull --rebase

is not being enforced