# How to find all commits associated with a merge commit in GIT?

Tags: git, githooks

I am working on a git pre-push update hook wherein I would like to check for a specific condition in a commit only if there is no merge commit associated with it. In case there is a commit with an associated merge commit, then I would like to skip checking the individual commit and check the merge commit instead.

In order to be able to do this, I would need to have the exact list of commits associated with a merge commit so that I can filter them out from the commit list which inturn contains the total list of commits getting pushed to remote.

Is there a git command/option to find the commit range merged in a Merge commit ?

For instance: I would like to get only the below highlighted text as the command output:

```
$ git log --merges
commit fd3d8c5bc3e689cf44b5ca1e8d06fe2a6bd02716
**Merge: f778e20 cefb2e9**
Author: abc <abc@abc.com>
Date:   Mon Aug 17 22:00:49 2015 -0700

Merge branch 'feature_personal'
```

I attempted to do the following:

```
$ git log --pretty=%P -n 1
f778e20d1bfa0b1821d93feca3863a69af48de1f cefb2e96279447b2c268167a2db3605b84717de
```

This works well when you use -n 1 which is doable on the client side but does not work out as part of a git hook on the server side. Is there a way to use SHA id of the merge commit and get these details ?

I would also like to get all the list of commits included in the range f778e20..cefb2e9. This would give me the total list of commits associated with the merge commit.

I tried using git rev-list f778e20..cefb2e9 but this lists a lot of commits.

Any suggestions/thoughts ?

Comment: Define "commits associated with a merge commit". Do you mean "the parents of a merge commit"? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
git log --oneline --merges <commit_hash_to> <commit_hash_from>
```

Below is the link to a question which provide details on choosing these hash (parents) to get clear range.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679870/list-commits-between-2-commit-hashes-in-git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679870/list-commits-between-2-commit-hashes-in-git)