# How to list commits directly between two tags

Tags: git

In order to create an automatic release notes tool, I created a script listing all commits between two tags. But in some case, the tools list more commits than I wanted.

For example, with the following graph :

```
* abc123 [v42] Merge branch foo on branch bar
|\
* | def465 ...
* | fba602 ...
| * da07b4 ...
* | 98dc92 [v41] ...
```

In this case, I want to list the commits directly between v41 and v42. I tried with `git log v41..v42` and `git log v41...v42` (as suggested by codeWizard) but git also includes the commit `da07b4` which is not a children of v41.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated  in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18680080/612206),

> "Between" is a somewhat slippery notion, when it comes to git commits.

In my case, I wanted to be sure to ignore commits which were not children of the first tag. here's the script i used, with the help of the `git merge-base` command which finds the nearest merge base ancestor.

```
#!/bin/bash

base_hash=`git log --format=%H -1 $1`

# list all commits between start and end of a version
git log --format="%H" $1^..$2 | while read commit_hash; do
    # check if this commit is reeaaaaally part of the release note
    merge_base=`git merge-base $1 ${commit_hash}`

    if [ "${merge_base}" = "${base_hash}" ]; then 
        # profit
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 4):

You can always use the `..` (known as `range`).

```
git log [first commit]..[second commit ] --pretty=oneline
```

This will show you all the commits in the given range.

---

#### What is the difference between `..` to `...`

[image]

[image]

---

#### `git log a..b`

means *give me all commits that were made since `a`, until and including `b`* (or, like the man page puts it "Include commits that are reachable from b but exclude those that are reachable from a"), the three-dot variant

#### `git log a...b`

means "Include commits that are reachable from either a or b but exclude those that are reachable from both", which is a totally different thing.