# How to get authors of changes between 2 commits?

Tags: git, author

I am trying to get authors of changes between 2 commits.

What would be the best for me is something like:

```
git diff --name-only master
```

but instead of

```
--name-only
```

parameter like

```
--authors-only
```

But unfortunately `diff` does not have such one. There is no restriction I have to use `diff` command, `git log` or others are also fine.

I need to it to blame people who caused tests to fail.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`git log --pretty=format:"%an" prevTestCommit..lastTestCommit | sort | uniq`

Comment: For some reason, this works for me only if I give short commit hash ids.

Answer (score 4):

you can use something like

```
git log --pretty=format:"%an %aE" f398e997ea9ad81e586b1f751693cd336963ba6a ^bb69eb11d979437a0b390ac9333342e7594c211c
```

where the format will print the author name and email and than the commits
see [List commits between 2 commit hashes in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679870/list-commits-between-2-commit-hashes-in-git)

for more information on how to use get the commits between two given commits.

Comment: For some reason signs " ^" betweend hashes does not work for me, I needed to  put ".." like stated in @DAle answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this exists per default, but you could specify a custom output format for `git log`:

```
git log --pretty="format:%an"
```

This would print only author names. For more details, see the section `PRETTY FORMATS` in `git log --help`