# Git log between two tags showing commits older than tags?

Tags: git, github, git-log

I am using `git log tag1..tag2` to see the commits made between `tag1` and `tag2` (where `tag1` is the older tag, and `tag2` is the newer). I expected to see the commits that were made between `tag1` and `tag2`, but I am also seeing commits that were made before `tag1`'s date. Why could this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into the fact that `commit1..commit2` doesn't mean what people first think it means.  In fact, this notation is just shorthand for `commit2 ^commit1`.  It means: *find commits reachable from `commit2`, excluding commit `commit1` and commits reachable from `commit1`.*

This "reachable from" notion is a bit tricky.  I like to think of it as "paint commits red or green temporarily".  Red means stop, and green means go, as usual.  We start with the latest commit and work backwards.  Red paint overrides green paint: a stopped-out commit stays stopped-out, even if something else would make it go.

Consider a commit graph like this one, where new commits are always added on the right:

```
                  tag:v2.0
                     |
                     v
                J1--J2   <-- release/2
               /
...--G--H--I--J--...   <-- mainline
         \
          H1--H2--H3--H4--H5   <-- release/1
               ^           ^
               |           |
            tag:v1.0    tag:v1.1
```

Here, we have released versions `1.0`, `1.1`, and `2.0` (tags with `v`), which correspond to commits `H2`, `H5`, and `J2` respectively.  The name `mainline` points to some commit after `J`, so if we use the name `mainline` as green/go, we get all its commits down to `J`, and continuing backwards to `I`, `H`, `G`, and so on.  We never "go right again" though, so we never paint any of the extra `Jn` or `Hn` commits green.  Similarly, if we pick `H2` to paint red, we paint `H2`, then `H1`, then `H`, and `G`, and so on all the way back to the left, but we never move rightward, so we don't touch `I` or anything further right.

Looking at commits `v1.0..v1.1` you will see commits `H5`, then `H4`, then `H3`.  They were painted green (by starting from `v1.1` aka `H5`), and never painted red (by starting from `v1.0` aka `H2`).  Looking at `v1.1..v2.0` you will see `J2`, then `J1`, then `J`, then `I`, then `H`.  That's all fine, and is probably what you expect.

But this graph is very linear.  Suppose we have some fork-and-merge behavior in the graph:

```
          G--H
         /    \
...--E--F      K--L   <-- branchname
         \    /
          I--J
```

and we pick commit `L` to start from, and `J` to stop at.  We paint `J` red, and `I` and `F` and `E` and so on are also all red.  Then we paint `L` green, and `K` green, and `H` green, and `G` green.  `F` is already red (or will be overridden with red if we do the red after the green).  The final list of commits, then, is `L`, `K`, `H`, and `G`, even though in some sense `G` is probably earlier than `J`.  The trick is that `G` is not *reachable from* `J`.  Git isn't going by dates at all: it's going by reachability in the commit graph.

See also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18680080/1256452) to [List commits between 2 commit hashes in git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18679870/1256452), and more generally, [Think like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate explanation.