# show commits contributing to diff between two commits

Tags: git

I'd like to get a summary of changes between two commits, using the commit messages. I found this thread, which almost does what I'm looking for:

[List commits between 2 commit hashes in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679870/list-commits-between-2-commit-hashes-in-git)

but the `--ancestry-path` tag doesn't show the commits that contribute to a merge commit in that chain. I'd like something similar, but follows the merge commits back to the common ancestor.

Comment: Does this not answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/1191282/989920

Comment: Please edit your title to ask a clear question. I'm not sure how to read that as a sentence.

Comment: Does dropping the --ancestry-path help ?

Comment: @LeGEC I suppose that should have been obvious...Make it an answer and I'll mark it accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you simply want to view `<commitA>..<commitB>` range, without using `--ancestry-path` :

```
git log <commitA>..<commitB>
git log --oneline --graph <commitA>..<commitB>
```