# git: get commits in order for changelog

Tags: git, jenkins, tags, git-commit, changelog

I am working on git following gitflow (with feature branches and hotfix).
Each commit is as follows " [ticket ID]: message "

With jenkins I would like to generate a changelog between 2 tags, but I don't know how to do this correctly.

If I do a `git log TagFrom...TagTo` it seems to order the commits by creation date this causes problems. The list of commits does not match how the changes have been released. However, the bitbucket website does show them in the correct order.

I have also tried git-changelog-command-line plugins but it seems to have the same issue.

What would be the correct way to get the changes between two tags working with this branch model.

The `git log --oneline` command seems to order them correctly.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to generate a changelog between 2 tags

You have two problems here:

1. The notion of "between" often doesn't make sense in a Git commit graph.
2. `git log` has to *sort* commits, and you wish to control the sort order.

Problem #2 *might* be solved for you by using `--topo-order` or other `git log` options.  But this is not clear to me, because you say:

> The `git log --oneline` command seems to order them correctly

and yet `--oneline` merely means `--pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit`; it does not imply `--topo-order`.  I *suspect* you may be combining it with `--graph` and `--graph` *does* imply `--topo-order`.

You *may* find that `--ancestry-path` helps with your notion of "between" for the tags.  You probably do *not* want the *three*-dot syntax `TagFrom...TagTo`, which means *commits reachable from either tag but not from both tags*.  You *may* want `TagOld..TagNew` and you may want to add `--ancestry-path`.  See also [List commits between 2 commit hashes in git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18679870/1256452).

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, I couldn't understand if the `--ancestry-path` option solves problem 1. So the command to use to get the new commits between two versions would be `git log --topo-order --ancestry-path  tagOld..tagNew`?

Comment: I did not say that it would solve it, I said that it *might* **help** with it. See the linked question and its accepted answer for details.