# How to download a multi commits from github?

Tags: github

I need to use `git format-patch` to download multi a commits depend on from some SHA to other SHA ... Not single diff patch ...

for example I want to download from this source
https://github.com/GStreamer/gstreamer/commits/main?after=93b896eb4edc035d9ccc56a680a34e83aa18bb42+34&branch=main&qualified_name=refs%2Fheads%2Fmain

I need to download all commits from (pbutils: descriptions: add meta/x-klv) to (ci: Bump meson to 0.62.2 in Fedora docker images) only ?!!
This is just example !!

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679870/list-commits-between-2-commit-hashes-in-git ?

Comment: Yes but did not help me ... I need to create patches from my locale source on linux not print list of commits from online .. with `git format-patch` ot any other commands

Comment: Either you don't understand git, or I don't understand your question. Git works with repositories, commits are changes to repositories. You can clone an entire repository, but it's quite unclear if you have done so. If you already have a local repository cloned from Github, why would you then download commits? And if you don't have a local repository, then why do you comment about "create patches from local source" ?

Comment: I need to download some patches commit around (50) from some repositories and then apply it on other project.... It is not important to collection patches from my locale. It is ok If there is any way yo download it online from source. But I need to download some commits (from some SHA to SHA)

Comment: Just to check, the "other project" is somehow related  so the patches do make sense, but git doesn't understand the connection? You lost the git history or so?

Comment: No. I did not lost (git history)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`format-patch` takes the usual `gitrevisions` format. Just leave out the `-1` (single commit) argument and specify `sha1...sha2` range.

Comment: How to use it gitrevisions to catch and download patches ?!! Can you give example please ?!

Comment: @fairbird: `gitrevisions` isn't a tool. It's the git format to specify what you want: one commit, all commits since a certain commit, or (for your case) a range. The example is already in: `sha1...sha2`, Those are the SHA hashes of the first and last commits.

Comment: I have understood what you advice but how to use it gitrevisions ?!! for example If I have from `sha1` to `sha100` and I want just download all commits just from `sha20` to `sha50` how to use `gitrevisions` ?!!

Answer (score 0):

found way by this commit

```
git format-patch bc6a2dd1c8552cd67612dc728e0b7525e90b036e -10
```

The command will be download patches start with bc6a2dd1c8552cd67612dc728e0b7525e90b036e and them latest 10 commits after that SHA