# Get commit hashes between 2 specified commit hash

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-commit, git-rev-list

What I am asking is somewhat similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679870/list-commits-between-2-commit-hashes-in-git/18680059#18680059). However, it doesn't solve my problem. I want to list the commit hashes present between a start hash and an end hash (including the start and end). Let me give a simple example. For [this](https://github.com/danilofes/refactoring-toy-example) repository, if we go to the commit history of the master branch, I want commits between `f3b628f8f9c71a2cdfa052025c4a1ed78ee4c45d` and `d4bce13a443cf12da40a77c16c1e591f4f985b47`. So I want the following commits to be printed -

```
f3b628f8f9c71a2cdfa052025c4a1ed78ee4c45d
c286db365e7374fe4d08f54077abb7fba81dd296
0bb0526b70870d57cbac9fcc8c4a7346a4ce5879
a5a7f852e45c7cadc8d1524bd4d14a1e39785aa5
9a5c33b16d07d62651ea80552e8782974c96bb8a
d4bce13a443cf12da40a77c16c1e591f4f985b47
```

I initially did something like this - `git rev-list --reverse --remotes ^f3b628f8f9c71a2cdfa052025c4a1ed78ee4c45d^ HEAD --` but it gave me incorrect results.

After that I did this `git rev-list --reverse --ancestry-path f3b628f8f9c71a2cdfa052025c4a1ed78ee4c45d..HEAD` which gave me all but the first (starting) commit correctly.

So if someone can please help me on this, I will be really grateful. Also, if possible, please explain the command that you're using and how it's selecting those commits only. Thank you.

Comment: To include the starting commit in `git log`/`git rev-list` results start with its parent commit (`~` or `^`): `git rev-list --reverse --ancestry-path f3b628f8f9c71a2cdfa052025c4a1ed78ee4c45d~..HEAD`

Comment: Using this commit gives an additional starting commit - `ef3422578c0bcaef1561980ef077d06c3f6fc9f9`

The full list generated - 

`ef3422578c0bcaef1561980ef077d06c3f6fc9f9
f3b628f8f9c71a2cdfa052025c4a1ed78ee4c45d
c286db365e7374fe4d08f54077abb7fba81dd296
0bb0526b70870d57cbac9fcc8c4a7346a4ce5879
a5a7f852e45c7cadc8d1524bd4d14a1e39785aa5
9a5c33b16d07d62651ea80552e8782974c96bb8a
d4bce13a443cf12da40a77c16c1e591f4f985b47`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git 2.38 added an optional argument to `--ancestry-path`, so now you can

```
git rev-list --ancestry-path=base base^! HEAD
```

which starts from `base` and `HEAD` and lists only commits with `base` in the path from those two tips but includes no ancestors *of* `base`.

```
$ git rev-list --reverse --ancestry-path=f3b6 f3b6^! d4bc
f3b628f8f9c71a2cdfa052025c4a1ed78ee4c45d
c286db365e7374fe4d08f54077abb7fba81dd296
0bb0526b70870d57cbac9fcc8c4a7346a4ce5879
a5a7f852e45c7cadc8d1524bd4d14a1e39785aa5
9a5c33b16d07d62651ea80552e8782974c96bb8a
d4bce13a443cf12da40a77c16c1e591f4f985b47
$
```

Even-harder-to-scrute (not actually inscrutable, just ... yeah, okay, this is wordplay, sue me) usages can get handy with that.

Before this addition, `--ancestry-path base^! tip` would include `base` but if it was a merge it would display reachable-from-tip children of `base`'s parents that did not trace ancestry through `base`.

Comment: Thank you. I guess this is the most appropriate answer and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
git rev-list --reverse --ancestry-path f3b628f^..
```

---

You almost had it with your last example, but the first hash is reachable from itself so excluded.

> The most common range specification is the double-dot syntax. This basically asks Git to resolve a range of commits that are reachable from one commit but aren’t reachable from another.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection

To include `f3b628f`, choose the parent commit: `f3b628f^`.

> If you place a ^ (caret) at the end of a reference, Git resolves it to mean the parent of that commit.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#_ancestry_references

Both the full hash and short hash work equally:

> Git is smart enough to figure out what commit you’re referring to if you provide the first few characters of the SHA-1 hash

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#_short_sha_1

and HEAD is implied:

> You can also leave off one side of the syntax to have Git assume HEAD.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#_short_sha_1

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I guess this is similar to what @phd commented. Using this it adds an additional commit - `ef34225`. But after your explanation, I guess this is because 'ef34225' is the parent of `f3b628f` and hence it gets included.